# Matlab large array (1e6 values) computation speed

Tags: arrays, matlab, statistics

I am trying to optimize a Matlab code for a statistic calculation for a large array of data (1e6 values). I tried several methods, with loops or fun functions, with diff or basic math. Basically I need to calculate an accumulation for a set of data and the standard deviation for it.

I cannot get this running under 24 seconds. Is there any way to improve this code, without using additional toolboxes?

Here is what I tried until now:

```
clear
close
myData = rand(1e5, 1)/5e6;

M = 1000;
N = length(myData)-M;

PkPk  = NaN(M, 1);
Std  = NaN(M, 1);
myMat = NaN (1, N);


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% peak2peak is part of  Signal Processing Toolbox:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% can use max()-min()
tic
for x = 1  : M
     myMat =    diff( (reshape(myData(1:x*floor(N/x)),x,floor(N/x)))')   ;
    PkPk (x) = peak2peak(myMat(:)) ;
    Std(x) = sqrt(sum(sum((myMat-mean(myMat(:))).^2))/numel(myMat));
end
Time1 = toc;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic
for x = 1  : M
    myMat =  bsxfun(@minus,  myData(x+1 : x+N) , myData(1:N)) '; % EDIT HERE: transpose
    PkPk (x) = peak2peak(myMat(:)) ; % max - min
    Std(x) = sqrt(sum(sum((myMat-mean(myMat(:))).^2))/numel(myMat)); % std
end
Time2 = toc;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic
for x = 1  : M
    myMat =   myData(x+1 : x+N) - myData(1:N);%
    PkPk (x) = peak2peak(myMat(:)) ; % max - min
    Std(x) = sqrt(sum(sum((myMat-mean(myMat(:))).^2))/numel(myMat)); % std
end
Time3 = toc;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic 
for x = 1  : M
Std(x) = std( reshape( diff(reshape( myData(1:x*floor(N/x))  , x ,floor(N/x))'),  floor(N/x)' * x -x, 1    )  ) ;
PkPk(x) = peak2peak( reshape( diff(reshape( myData(1:x*floor(N/x))  , x ,floor(N/x))'),  floor(N/x)' * x -x, 1    )  ); 
end
Time4 =toc;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic
for x = 1  : M
PkPk (M) = peak2peak( myData(x+1 : x+N) - myData(1:N)) ;
Std(M) = std( myData(x+1 : x+N) - myData(1:N)) ;
end
Time5 =toc;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic 
PkPk = (cellfun(@(x)  peak2peak( reshape( diff(reshape( myData(1:x*floor(N/x))  , x ,floor(N/x))'),  floor(N/x)' * x -x, 1    )  )  ,  num2cell(1:M)   ));
Std = (cellfun(@(x)  std( reshape( diff(reshape( myData(1:x*floor(N/x))  , x ,floor(N/x))'),  floor(N/x)' * x -x, 1    )  )  ,  num2cell(1:M)   ));
Time6 =toc;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic  
PkPk = cellfun( @(x)  peak2peak(    myData(x:N+x-1) - myData(1:N)     )    ,  num2cell(1:M) )  ;
Std = cellfun( @(x)  std(    myData(x:N+x-1) - myData(1:N)     )    ,  num2cell(1:M) )  ;
Time7 =toc;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

tic 
Std = cellfun( @(x)  std( myData(x+1 : x+N) - myData(1:N)), num2cell(1:M) ) ;
PkPk  = cellfun( @(x)  max( myData(x+1 : x+N) - myData(1:N)) - min( myData(x+1 : x+N) - myData(1:N)) , num2cell(1:M) );
Time8 =toc;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic
Std = arrayfun( @(x)  std( myData(x+1 : x+N) - myData(1:N)), (1:M) ) ;
PkPk  = arrayfun( @(x)  peak2peak( myData(x+1 : x+N) - myData(1:N))  , (1:M) );
Time9 =toc;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

And here are my time results(in seconds):

```
Time1: 24.47
Time2: 23.56
Time3: 25.20
Time4: 45.44
Time5: 42.99
Time6: 46.27
Time7: 43.62
Time8: 62.49
Time9: 41.69
```

Thank you!

Comment: That's weird. What's your system specs? I ran your code here (Core i7) and got this: Time1: 0.6373
Time2: 0.5768
Time3: 0.5231
Time4: 1.4072
Time5: 0.8793
Time6: 1.0150
Time7: 0.9185
Time8: 1.1790
Time9: 0.8692

Comment: Whoops, forget, I figured it out: you said on the description the array has 1e6 values, but on your code it has 1e5 values. Updated it, ran again and now the times are large too. :P

Comment: Your first and second solution produces a different output.

Comment: @Daniel: Thank you for pointing it out. I added an edit to fix this (@method2, myMat -> myMat').

Answer (score 1):

I took your second solution (the fastest on your benchmark) and did some modifications.

A performance improvement can be achieved if you stop acessing `myData(1:N)` every loop iteration and assign it to an array before the loop, like this:

```
tic
myData1toN = myData(1:N);
for x = 1  : M
    myMat =  bsxfun(@minus,  myData(x+1 : x+N) , myData1toN);
    PkPk (x) = peak2peak(myMat(:)) ; % max - min
    Std(x) = sqrt(sum(sum((myMat-mean(myMat(:))).^2))/numel(myMat)); % std
end
clear myData1toN;
Time2 = toc
```

**Time before:**

```
Time2: 20.5618
```

**Time after:**

```
Time2: 14.2260
```

Another modification: the `sum(sum(...` can be changed to just `sum(...`, because the outer sum is just summing a single value.

**Time after:**

```
Time2: 11.6573
```

By the way, `numel(myMat)` can be replaced by `N`, but I didn't note a performance improvement.

Comment: Hello!
This improved my timing from 23.21sec to 16.04 sec. sum(sum()) is a leftover from the first method. I am focusing now on improving the time of the first line in the loop. It is the most time consuming (>50%)

Thank you!

Comment: you don't need ``bsxfun`` here - you can simply use ``myData(x+1 : x+N) - myData1toN``